# Inbreeding calculation in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a script that calculates inbreeding for at least 10 generation.
I only have access to php & mysql.

Here is an example of the formula:
http://www.highflyer.supanet.com/coefficient.htm

I have looked at pre-written scripts but the ones I find are not in php.

Can someone please point me in the direction I need to be looking to achieve this script?  Or outline a way of going about doing this project?
I realize I need to check every ancestor to see how many times they show up, what would be the most logical way to go about doing that?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

```
                 Sire's Sire (WALT)
         Sire1
                 Sire's Dam

Person1
                 Dam's Sire (WALT)
         Dam1
                 Dam's Dam
```

```
$n1 = 1; //# of generations from sire to common ancestor
$n2 = 1; //# of generation from the dam to common ancestor
$Fa = 0; //inbreeding coi of common ancestor

$n = $n1+$n2+1;  // n1+n2+1
$F = 1+$Fa;  // (1)

//inbreeding equation
$x = pow((.5),$n)*$F;

echo "<p class=\"coi\">Inbreeding COI: ".$x."</p>";
```

I wrote the above code for the above pedigree, using the pedigree in the link as an example and what I based my data and conclusion off of.
I'm guessing I'm going to need some sort of loop to check generations from sire to common ancestors...

My end goal is to be able to plugin an ID# and it return the COI for 10 generation of ID.  I'm not sure what would be the best path to accomplish this with dynamic data.
Thanks

Comment: Start by writing the output of inbreeding for 1 generation and see if you can get it to work. Worry about expansion later. If you can't wrap your head around the big stuff, start little.

Comment: Also make sure you understand the maths to the formula and theory behind it else you can't bend the data or steps to calculate the data to your will. Limiting your options on writing the code for it.

Comment: I've added some changes to my post above to update on my progress.  Anymore words of wisdom on which direction i should take now?

Comment: I'm looking for a better way to step through the data of the tree for comparison  than checking each one, one at a time.  I'll eventually be checking 2042 records once my project is complete.

Comment: It looks to me like you are almost done. If you have the data ready of all the Coefficients `Fa` you can just roll through them with variable generations.